# Blurry background on modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, simplemodal

How to have a blurred background instead of the white background when popup is opened ?
I would like to add :

```
-webkit-filter: blur(8px);
-ms-filter: blur(8px);
filter: blur(8px);
-moz-filter: blur(8px);
-o-filter: blur(8px);
```

on
    `.splash { background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);}`
but the blur is in the fullpage, popup included. Someone can help, here is a jsfiddle demo:   https://jsfiddle.net/kodjoe/dgykn78o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give blur properties to .wrapper. You'll achieve what you want.

```
.wrapper{
    -webkit-filter: blur(8px);
    -ms-filter: blur(8px);
    -moz-filter: blur(8px);
    -o-filter: blur(8px);
    filter: blur(8px);
}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, you're right but when you close the popup the page stay blurred, or i want it blur only when the popup is open, we're close !!!

Comment: you need to add class to wrapper and remove it on close.

Comment: yes all works when i add that .CoverPop-open .wrapper